# Is updating one field in an existing document considered a write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app keeps track of current views for a video. I was confused if just one variable in that document is considered a write or if creating a NEW document in that collection is a write. I want to make sure I understand this correctly because of the pricing around reads & writes.

Here is an example of what I would do.

```
{
   "video-doc1"
      - "views": 12
      - (other document data)
   "video-doc2"
      - "views": 45
      - (other document data)
}

//After Update

{
   "video-doc1"
      - "views": 13 //+1 Here
      - (other document data)
   "video-doc2"
      - "views": 45
      - (other document data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time a document is created or changed, it counts as a document write.